# git-config style configuration system

Tags: git, configuration

What system does `git-config` use to manage configuration? Is it something that's publicly available as a stand-alone library/tool? or is it tightly interwined into git?

I'd like to have something like it for my project.

Is there a library that I can use which provides similar functionality? Or should I just write my own tool/library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [Chris Johnsen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720057/git-config-style-configuration-system/1720457#1720457): there is [Config::GitLike](http://p3rl.org/Config::GitLike) Perl module on CPAN.
<sub>*It is not part of Git project*</sub>

Answer (score 6):

For Python, seems ConfigParser cannot be used directly due to the leading spaces in git config file. But it could be used in this way

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
from StringIO import StringIO

with open('.gitconfig') as f:
    c = f.readlines()
cp = ConfigParser()
cp.readfp(StringIO(''.join([l.lstrip() for l in c])))
```

Comment: Additional data in a section header is unavailable via `ConfigParser`, e.g. `[submodule "my/submodule/name"]` in the `.gitmodules` file

Answer (score 4):

The code is custom. [Have a look for yourself](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=tree) (see builtin-config.c, config.c).

See the license ([GPL v2](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=COPYING;hb=HEAD)) for details on reuse.

It is not a generic library, nor is it a generic tool (though you might be able to use it as one if you alway pass `--file` and are OK with the way it does subsections), so it will take some work to adapt the code.

Answer (score 2):

For Java, here you have a very small library: [gitconfig4j](http://timoteoponce.github.com/gitconfig4j/)

Answer (score 0):

For Python, there is the [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) module, which uses a similar file format.

Comment: You actually cannot use ConfigParser directly, as Linus decided to put tabs in the format for some reason.  See Congbin Guo's answer.