# Convert .gitmodules into a parsable format for iteration using Bash

Tags: bash, git, git-submodules

### Background

I would like to make a shell function that takes `.gitmodules` and iterates over each module executing certain commands based off of each submodules properties (e.g. `<PATH>` or `<URL>` or `<BRANCH>`).

➡️ The default format of `.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "PATH"]
    path = <PATH>
    url = <URL>
[submodule "PATH"]
    path = <PATH>
    url = <URL>
    branch = <BRANCH>
```

➡️ Pseudocode:

```
def install_modules() {
    modules = new list

    fill each index of the modules list with each submodule & its properties

    iteratate over modules
       if module @ 'path' contains a specified 'branch':
          git submodule add -b 'branch' 'url' 'path'
       else:
          git submodule add 'url' 'path'
}
```

### ⚠️ Current `install_modules()`

```
# currently works for grabbing the first line of the file
# doesn't work for each line after.
install_modules() {
    declare -A regex

    regex["module"]='\[submodule "(.*)"\]'
    regex["url"]='url = "(.*)"'
    regex["branch"]='branch = "(.*)"'

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    cat < ".gitmodules" | while read -r LINE; do
        if [[ $LINE =~ ${regex[module]} ]]; then
            PATH=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

            echo "$PATH"
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate but looks relevant: [How do I grab an INI value within a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318809/how-do-i-grab-an-ini-value-within-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little help from [@phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) and [Restore git submodules from .gitmodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11258810/7976758) (which [@phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) pointed me towards), I was able to construct the function that I needed.

### `install_submodules()`

⚠️ *Note*: *Assume `$REPO_PATH` is declared & initialized.*

⚠️ *My answer is an adaptation from [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53269641/5290011.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53269641/5290011._)*

```
install_submodules() {
    git -C "${REPO_PATH}" config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp '^submodule\..*\.path$' |
        while read -r KEY MODULE_PATH
        do
            # If the module's path exists, remove it.
            # This is done b/c the module's path is currently 
            # not a valid git repo and adding the submodule will cause an error.
            [ -d "${MODULE_PATH}" ] && sudo rm -rf "${MODULE_PATH}"

            NAME="$(echo "${KEY}" | sed 's/^submodule\.\(.*\)\.path$/\1/')"

            url_key="$(echo "${KEY}" | sed 's/\.path$/.url/')"
            branch_key="$(echo "${KEY}" | sed 's/\.path$/.branch/')"

            URL="$(git config -f .gitmodules --get "${url_key}")"
            BRANCH="$(git config -f .gitmodules --get "${branch_key}" || echo "master")"

            git -C "${REPO_PATH}" submodule add --force -b "${BRANCH}" --name "${NAME}" "${URL}" "${MODULE_PATH}" || continue
        done

    git -C "${REPO_PATH}" submodule update --init --recursive
}
```

Comment: Recommended minor tweak: in the sed expressions, add an anchor (`path$` rather than just `path`) so that an Evil Submodule whose path is, say, `x.path` won't be translated into `NAME=x` but rather into `NAME=x.path`.

Comment: Nice script. Thank you! For me I was missing the "-C "${REPO_PATH}"" part in when setting the URL and BRANCH variables. Those commands return nothing when the working directory is not inside the REPO_PATH

Answer (score 8):

`.gitmodules` is a `.gitconfig`-like file so you can use `git config` to read it. For example, read all values from a `.gitmodules`, split values by `=` (key=value), and split keys by `.`:

```
git config -f .gitmodules -l | awk '{split($0, a, /=/); split(a[1], b, /\./); print b[1], b[2], b[3], a[2]}'
```

`git config -f .gitmodules -l` prints something like

```
submodule.native/inotify_simple.path=native/inotify_simple
submodule.native/inotify_simple.url=https://github.com/chrisjbillington/inotify_simple
```

and `awk` output would be

```
submodule native/inotify_simple path native/inotify_simple
submodule native/inotify_simple url https://github.com/chrisjbillington/inotify_simple
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! How would I modify to read from the file itself without using `git config`?

Comment: I don't know. I don't see a reason to avoid `git config` and `awk` is not my preferred language. Would I want to parse `.gitmodules` without `git config` I'd use a different language — Perl or Python — and a library to parse `.gitconfig`-like modules: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1720057/7976758

Comment: Okay. My use case is when I add `.gitmodules` to a locally initialized`git` repo that doesn't actually contain a `.gitmodules` file. So, I would like to read from the file iteratively executing `git submodule add` for each submodule within the file. I know its odd, but its for a reason.

Comment: I don't see a reason to avoid `git config` in this case. You have `git` anyway, you gonna run `git submodule`, why not `git config`? You probably need to name the file differently so that `git submodule add` wouldn't clobber it.

Comment: The reason is that my locally initialized git repo doesn't have git submodules. So 'git config -f .gitmodules -l' will return nothing.

Comment: `git config -f` can read any file. You said you're going to use an existing `.gitmodules`…

Comment: Also worth mentioning: `git config` can read a config file by its blob hash ID or other suitable revision string, directly from a Git repository. Git grew this ability long ago precisely *because* Git needs to read submodule information from `.gitmodules` files that are not necessarily extracted to the file system. Hence, you can do `GIT_DIR=$path_to_repo/.git git config --blob <whatever> --get ...`. The documentation suggests using, e.g., `--blob master:.gitmodules`.