# How to update git submodules when .gitmodules was manually changed?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Even though this issue was addressed in other posts, I could not find an answer that worked for me.

My Problem: I manually made changes to my `.gitmodules` file, both adding and removing modules. I would like to my submodules folder to represent those changes.

Approach:

```
rm -rf submodules/
mkdir submodules/
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

This seems to do nothing.

I also tried the same with `git pull --recurse-submodules` and `git submodule update --recursive --remote`. Still nothing.

Is there a cache entry I have to delete in `.git/`?

I **don't** want to use `git add xyz` manually over and over, pls!

Comment: try adding `-f` to force. You might also have to run `git submodule sync` before trying to update.

Comment: `git pull --recurse-submodules -f` tells me that my submodules are already up to date

Comment: `git submodule update --init --recursive -f` does nothing

Comment: Are you sure that I do not have to delete `.git/config` or `.git/modules/`?

Comment: See the script at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53899440/7976758 — it runs `git submodule add --force` in a loop for you. As for deleted submodules — you have to remove them from `.git/config`.